# how to run a bound service in different thread

Tags: android

My application uses the camera, it displays the camera preview, and on every preview frame it encodes the frame data to base64 form to call my remote web service.

Since the speed of producing frame doesn't match the speed of consuming frame(calling web service), I consider to use a buffer(message queue) in my service, so I use Messenger to bind the service.

Therefore, I consider to use the Service, and bind it to my CameraActivity. By default the service runs in the same thread as the UI thread, however, I want to run the service in another thread. I've read the [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#top_of_page) and the [Bound service](https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/components/bound-services.html#Creating), they just mention that I can run the service in other thread but don't give an example.

**CameraActivity**

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Camera.PreviewCallback {
    private Camera camera;
    private CameraPreview preview;
    int cnt = 0, RATE = 0;
    private Messenger messenger;//use to communicate with CloudService
    private boolean bound = false;

    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            messenger = new Messenger(service);
            bound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            messenger = null;
            bound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        camera = getCamera();
        RATE = camera.getParameters().getPreviewFrameRate() / 5;
        preview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
        FrameLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        layout.addView(preview);

        bindService(new Intent(this, CloudService.class), connection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    public static Camera getCamera() {
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        if (cnt == RATE) {
            if (bound) {
                Message message = Message.obtain(null, 0, data);
                try {
                    messenger.send(message);
                    Log.d("activity", "send msg");
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            cnt = 0;
        }
        cnt++;
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (bound){
            unbindService(connection);
            bound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**CloudService**

```
    private Thread thread;
    private Messenger messenger;

    public CloudService() {
        Log.d("cloud service", "create");
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("cloud service", "thread running");
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        messenger = new Messenger(new PreviewHandler(this));
        return messenger.getBinder();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("cloud service", "start");
        thread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        thread.interrupt();
        Log.d("cloud service", "destroy");
    }

    static class PreviewHandler extends Handler {
        private CloudService service;

        public PreviewHandler(CloudService service) {
            this.service = service;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            byte[] data = (byte[]) message.obj;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("message", "msg!!!");
        }
    }

}
```

How can I use thread in my CloudService properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Using `HandlerThread` and `Handler` together to achieve your task.

```
public class CloudService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "CloudService";

    private HandlerThread handlerThread;
    private PreviewHandler handler;
    private Messenger messenger;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        handlerThread = new HandlerThread("CloudService_HandlerThread");
        handlerThread.start();
        handler = new PreviewHandler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind");

        messenger = new Messenger(handler);
        return messenger.getBinder();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        handlerThread.quit();
    }

    static class PreviewHandler extends Handler {
        PreviewHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            byte[] data = (byte[]) message.obj;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage from thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to here that. Happy coding :)